# Canonical form of a PDE of order 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We consider the following PDE:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+3\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+4u=0$$

We have $B^2-AC=1^2-1\times 1=0$ then the PDE is Parabolic.

Could you please help me to find the canonical form of this PDE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the transformation $u(x,y) \mapsto u(\xi)$, with $\xi  = x+y$ given by one of the characteristics, then your PDE reduces to the ODE $u''(\xi)+ \frac{3}{4}u'(\xi) + 4 u(\xi) = 0$, whose solution is some combination of sine/cosine times an exponential. By reverting the transformation, one can show that $u(x+y)$ is indeed a solution of the original PDE.

For a more general integral, I think you need to specify another expression for the second characteristic $\eta = f(x,y)$ and then apply the transformation $u(x,y)\mapsto u(\xi,\eta)$. However, $f$ is somehow arbitrary and I haven't found a choice of $f$ so as to make the resulting PDE easy to solve.

I hope this helps.